# Typescript - write ES6 modules and transpile to Node

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-modules, es6-modules, transpiler

I use typescript to make NPM module and I write modules like `export default xyz;` but I'd like TSC to translate it to CommonJS on transpilation.

And I want to keep `const` and other ES6, just need the exports to be Node...

I've tried many TSCONFIG, as advised in some topics, currently it looks like

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "sourceRoot": "",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/main.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": []
}
```

but it still produces JS file with `export default xyz` instead of `module.exports = xyz`.

How do I make it work?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define in your config which module code should be generated by the typescript compiler.

```
{
  ...
  "module": "CommonJS",
  ...
}
```

[ref](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for creating Node16 module from ES6 `import/export` and I think I just didn't combine it properly.

Thanks to @jonrsharpe, found the option is `modules`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "Node16",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "sourceRoot": "",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/main.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": []
}
```